# Android - how to display an activity just for 1 time?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'd like to make a welcome screen just for 1 time. It should not be a splash screen because I'd put a TextEdit and a button to get the user's username. I need to see some examples of the code that would do it, thanks for stopping by! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** First let the user insert his Username in the TextView.

**2.** When the user press the Button, then do the following...

**-** Use `Intent` to move to the next Activity you want to divert him after this Staring Activiy.

**Eg:**

```
    Intent i = new Intent(StartActivity.this, DesiredActivity.class);
```

**-**   Now after you use `startActivity()` method with `Intent` as the argument, do use `finish()` method, that will remove this **StartActivity from the Back-Stack.**

**Eg:**

```
    Intent i = new Intent(StartActivity.this, DesiredActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

Now if the user press `back button` from the `DesiredActivity`( the one you went from `StartActivity`), **the app will exit.**

**////////////Edited Part/////////////////**

You don't want you app not to go to the First activity again, where you have already given the username.. After the first time..right ??????

**-** Then to do this... i will recommend you to do the below....

**i.** First **save the username** that user inputs the first time into `Shared Preference` **or** into a `file`, **or** a `Database`.

**ii.** Now when you open you app, let there be a `thread` which **checks the existence of the username** in the Shared Preference or in a file, or a Database, resp wherever u have saved it.

**iii.** If found let it move to the desired activity, if not prompt him to input the username, **thats what happen the 1st time you open your app.**

**iv.** Now its also about **user-friendliness**, so i recommend you to use a `splash activity` in the beginning, and fire your checking thread from here. So the user wont feel awkward looking at the blank screen while the thread checks the username

Comment: yes, but when I open the app again, it starts from the first app again

Comment: `it starts from first app again`, sorry but i think its first activity... ok now i got what u meant... see my edited part...

Comment: oh! so that's what splash activity are actually for! I'll try it as soon as possible, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start the activity. In `OnCreate`, check if the `Activity` already has been shown. If yes, start the next activity, if not, save that you are showing the activity now.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `Activity` in `onCreate` method check if user already enter UserName, if Yes start Another Activity immediately or show user Activity to enter user name.

Hope you are storing user name somewhere to check it if it is present or not

Answer (score 0):

Have a `starting activity` that will decide if the next activity that should be opened is the once-off welcome screen or the other part of your app.

In the first activity:
To know if the screen has been opened before, you'll have to save a boolean value to the phone's memory:
If the read boolean value is false (screen has not been opened before), show the once-off screen.
Else the screen has been opened before and that's why you'll advance to the other part of the app.

To save boolean value:

```
public void writePrimitiveInternalMemory(String filename, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = game.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(filename, value);
        editor.commit();

    }
```

To read boolean value:

```
public boolean readPrimitiveInternalMemoryBoolean(String filename) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = game.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getBoolean(filename, false);

    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: if I may ask, what is the main function of "value" in writePrimitiveInternalMemory(String filename, boolean value)?

Comment: The value of the boolean (true/false) you would like to save the the filename.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to Android so I need your further assistance. First, I assume that "game" in your code is a class where you want to save the preferences, then is it okay to change it to "this"?

Comment: Secondly, based on your description, writePrimitiveInternalMemory method consist of a String (name of the preference) and a boolean value (true or not whether we want to save the name). Then I wonder why readPrimitiveInternalMemoryBoolean returns the boolean value to false? Isn't it mean it would discard my preferences?

Comment: No, writePrimitiveInternalMemory takes a string (the filename) and a boolean (that value you wish to save to the file).